# What is the proper way to get access token after authenticating using /authorize and /oauth/token endpoints to access custom Api's

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, auth0

I have a spring boot Java backend and a ReactJs front end. My landing page has a Welcome button with a link to the Auth0 login page using the Authorization code flow. The url is  /authorize?client_id&client_secret etc. After login I get an authorization code that I use to POST to /oauth/token endpoint to get the ID_TOKEN and the ACCESS_TOKEN. I have custom API's on my Java Backend that I need to access but I am getting a 403 forbidden when I add use the ACCESS_TOKEN as the authorization header. I must be missing something?

Please help me, I've been fighting with this for a while. If I need to put more information, please let me know.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    http.sessionManagement()
                 .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .cors()
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .and()
                    .anonymous()
                    .and()
                    .servletApi()
                    .and()
                    .headers()
                    .cacheControl()
                    .and()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/app/cfg/ext/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/user").authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(LOGIN_URL)
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .addFilterBefore(
                            new CorsFilter(configSource), SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
                    .addFilterBefore(
                            new AuthTokenFilter(
                                    LOGIN_URL,
                                    new Auth0AccessTokenRequester(remoteEndpointService),
                                    successHandler),
                            SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class);
    
    
            http.csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(new CookieCsrfTokenRepository())
                    .and()
                    .addFilterAfter(
                            new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class);
            http.csrf().disable();
    }
```

Comment: #1 Did you configure the [api permissions](https://auth0.com/docs/configure/apis/add-api-permissions)?  #2 Did you configure the [role permissions](https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/rbac/roles/add-permissions-to-roles)? #3 Are you using the [@PreAutHorize](https://auth0.com/blog/spring-boot-authorization-tutorial-secure-an-api-java/) in your spring boot api?

Comment: I do have the api and role permissions set up. I did add the @PreAuthorize in the controller but I'm still receiving the 403 Forbidden error message.